# AJAX Call returning 404(Local) in IIS 7.5 but same works in other IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, deployment, iis-7.5

Am having the AJAX calls to my controller in my MVC Application

```
Controller/FunctionName



$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/Controller/FunctionName',
        .
        .
        .
        )};
```

Am using MVC 4 and making use of `JQUERY Ajax` function  as shown in the above code. It works totally fine when i run from Visual studio.

**I depolyed this to the server machine and as expected it works fine**. No issues found in AJAX calls.

**Now am trying to deploy this in my local machine IIS** which is same as my server version `(IIS 7.5)` but am getting `404` for all the ajax calls in firebug.

I verified the build and even i pointed to my web folder and am still looking for what went wrong !!

It works in other IIS so It wont be a URL resolving issue is my gues. Am i missing any settings or Any timely idea to fix this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's normal. You have hardcoded the url to your controller action:

```
url: '/Controller/FunctionName',
```

If you deploy your application in a virtual directory in IIS the correct url should be:

```
url: '/YourAppName/Controller/FunctionName',
```

That's the reason why you should absolutely never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application but ALWAYS use url helpers to generate it:

```
url: '@Url.Action("FunctionName", "Controller")',
```

and if this AJAX call is in a separate javascript file where you cannot use server side helpers, then you could read this url from some DOM element that you are AJAXifying.

For example let's suppose that you had an anchor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "FunctionName", "Controller", null, new { id = "myLink" })
```

that you AJAXify:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        .
        .
        .
    )};    
    return false;
});
```

Notice how we are reading the url from the DOM element which was generated by a helper.

Conclusion and 2 rules of thumb:

- **NEVER EVER** hardcode an url in an ASP.NET MVC application
- **ABSOLUTELY ALWAYS** use url helpers when dealing with urls in an ASP.NET MVC application

Comment: Totally Agree with you @Darin . How does it work in one IIS but not in other ?

Comment: @Darin Same Question. If it works in other IIS why not in the other ?

Comment: That would depend on how the application is configured - whether it is directly deployed in a website or as virtual directory.

Comment: @Darin One Last question am writing this in a Javascript. i got your Actionlink Example. Bt can you update the same scenario on Button click. How do i get those links ?

Comment: You could embed the link into the button as HTML5 data-* attribute: `<input type="button" id="myButton" data-url="@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")" value="click me" />` and then in your separate javascript file you would subscribe to the .click event of this button and retrieve the url using var `url = $(this).data('url');`.

Comment: @Darin  Great ! Any other approach as we are not using html5 yet. How do i handle this if am not using HTML5.  and Thanks for wonderful answers !

Comment: @Darin  Great ! Any other approach as we are not using html5 yet. How do i handle this if am not using HTML5.  and Thanks for wonderful answers !

Comment: Holy snit. After 2 hours of searching and debugging, this has solved my problem. I am now sending URLs to call from AJAX to AngularJS.

Answer (score 4):

Just a complement of [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337789/ajax-call-returning-404local-in-iis-7-5-but-same-works-in-other-iis/17337834#17337834) that if "the AJAX call is in a separate javascript file where you cannot use server side helpers", use a hidden field to store the url endpoint in the view:

```
@* file.cshtml *@
@* Method name and Controller, used in scripts/myfile.js *@
@Html.Hidden("URLEndpointName", Url.Action("FunctionName", "Controller"))
```

which is rendered into HTML as:

```html
<input id="URLEndpointName" name="URLEndpointName" type="hidden" value="/YourApp/Controller/FunctionName">
```

and read that hidden field in your js:

```js
// myfile.js
$.ajax({
    url: $("#URLEndpointName").val(),
    // Additional code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double dot in the url:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '../ControllerName/ActionName',
   .......
});
```

Comment: This solves the problem for me. In my case Url.Action("FunctionName", "Controller") is not returning the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd found on my setup of IIS7.5 is that the 'Handler Mapping' has a resource named 'OPTIONSVerbHandler' is not set in the right order hence return back as Unknown.

This work for me where my localhost ajax was calling my network server, which has a different name, that it shouldn't give me a CORS issue, but it did and this was my solution.

Open IIS and click on your server name on the left pane.  On the right pane double-click 'Handler Mappings' in the middle pane.  On the right pane, select 'View Ordered List'.  From there find 'OPTIONSVerbHandler' and 'svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit', move 'OPTIONSVerbHandler' up until it is above 'svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit'.

Make sure your 'handler' inside your ajax call does not have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in it.