# Getting relative path for generic handler in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got stuck into some weird situation related to path for generic handler (.ashx).

Ajax post is being made to handler. (Note: i have not applied / before Handler)

```
ajaxCallUrl: "Handler/RequestHandler.ashx"
```

After hosting on virtual directory in iis, url need to get changed like

```
ajaxCallUrl: "App/Handler/RequestHandler.ashx"
```

I trying using VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Handler/RequestHandler.ashx")

Also i have seeing the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337789/ajax-call-returning-404local-in-iis-7-5-but-same-works-in-other-iis)
(related to mine) showing getting url from Action Link but how in case of Handler?

Pls suggest any solution

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359816/can-asp-net-routing-be-used-to-create-clean-urls-for-ashx-ihttphander-handl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the right path, regardsless of the virtual directory you are currently in, you can use the [`UrlHelper.Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) helper method to get the right path:

```
"@Url.Content("~/Handler/RequestHandler.ashx")"
```

The `~/` in the path will make it a path relative to the application.